# Web VLC Player mp3 streaming from usb.hdd via 192.168.x.x:8090

Tags: hard-disk, vlc, web, mp3

Hi this works till now with my online links, but I can't get any music from my offline usb.hdd.

Via console it works with the comment

> vlc play
>   /media/pi/fmgNAS/Music/90_Discoteque_Mix_Vol.1/Scooter_-_Friends_Maxi.mp3

But via a only One Song or alls songs from my usb HDD won't play

I created a autostart via systemd service from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VLC_media_player

The vlc.service file includes this:

> [Unit] Description=VideoOnLAN Service After=network.target
>
> [Service] Type=forking User=vlcd ExecStart=/usr/bin/vlc play
>   /home/pi/playlist.xspf --daemon --syslog -I http --http-port 8090
>   --http-password PASS  Restart=on-abort
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target

My playlist.xspf is here:

> Playlist
>       /home/pi/playlist.xspf
>       
>           
>               Pause
>                 vlc://pause:60
>             60 
>               
>               0
>               
>           
>           
>               BB Radio 90's
>                 http://streambbr.ir-media-tec.com/90s/mp3-128/radioplayer_web/play.mp3
>               
>               1
>               
>           
>         
>               All Songs from my usb HDD
>                 file:///home/pi/playlist.Platte.m3u
>               
>               2
>               
>           
>           
>               One Song from my usb HDD
>          file:///media/pi/fmgNAS/Music/90_Discoteque_Mix_Vol.1/Scooter_-_Friends_Maxi.mp3
>               
>               3

Do I need to give the user vlcd some rights?

> pi@Loader:~ $ ls -l /media/pi/fmgNAS/Musik/ total 873733 drwx------ 1
>   pi pi      8192 Nov 19 12:54 90_Discoteque_Mix_Vol.1 drwx------ 1 pi
>   pi      8192 Nov 24  2015 90's Discoteque Mix Vol 2

What do i made wrong?